# Upload file to Django with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have simple fetch function and I want to upload an base64 image. The function is as follows:

```
function upload_to_server(canvasData){
    console.log(canvasData); // that is data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh.......
    return fetch(api_url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: {photo: canvasData}
    }).then(function (value) {
        if(value.ok){
            return value.json().then(function (response) {
                debugger;
            })
        }
    }).catch(function (reason) {
        debugger;
    })
}
```

And I have simple django view:

```
def upload_image(request):
    print(request.POST)
    pdb.set_trace()
```

It goes successful to that view when function `upload_to_server` gets called, but `request.POST` is empty. It shouldn't be empty, it should have key `photo` with that base64 value.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: would you be considering to use jQuery ajax? Also if you manually inspect the request in your web browser, is it a POST, and does it contain the `canvasData` in the payload?

Comment: It seems you need to `JSON.stringify({photo: canvasData})`

Comment: have you checked if it's in request.FILES?

Comment: @Sraw I tried it. The same problem.

Comment: @kujosHeist Yes. That is also empty. But it should be in files, because base64 is just a string.

Comment: @N.Ivanov I want to do it with `fetch`. How can I test it in my browser, in network tab?

Comment: yep, just open up the network tab, make the request, and then inspect if everything looks ok. Things to look for: check if method is post, check if the data is present in the request body. Hope this helps!

Comment: Strange, I have tried `body: JSON.stringify({photo: canvasData})`, it works well. If you don't stringify it, there isn't any payload.

Comment: Don't send the `headers : application/json` because you are sending image data.

Answer (score 2):

*If someone else has the same problem. I solved it as follows.*

I changed the body of fetch request to:

```
body: JSON.stringify({photo: canvasData})
```

and I changed `django` view, because data is in `request.body` and not in `request.POST`

```
import json
def upload_image(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    photo = body['photo']
    // Rest of the code
```

**EXTRA**

The photo is base64 encoded but I needed it as media file. I converted it to media file and saved it to database as follows:

```
def upload_image(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    photo = body['photo']
    img_format, img_str = photo.split(';base64,')
    ext = img_format.split('/')[-1]

    data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(img_str), name='temp.' + ext)  # You can save this as file instance.
    try:
        n_file = Files()
        n_file.file = data
        n_file.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    except Exception as err:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'failed'})
```